# Add lifecon package to project

Tags: packages

I would use actuarial symbols in my documents. Here we have lots of example:
http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/AMII/LifeConSymbolsGuide.pdf

some of them need `lifecon` package. Could you tell me how can I add it? If I add `\usepackage{lifecon}` it doesn't work:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `lifecon.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read >
```

Coule you tell me how can I add it?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the file from

http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/AMII/lifecon.sty

and stick it in the same directory as your document, then

```
\usepackage{lifecon}
```

should work

Comment: Unfortunataely, I have this file in the same folder as my document. It isn't working. There is the same error.

Comment: @Tomek You can't get a file not found error if it's in the same directory (if tex can find the document file). (That doesn't mean it doesn't happen (computers can have bugs:-) but since it is not supposed to be possible there is isn't much we can say without more example, in particular an example document, a directory listing, anything else that would help someone suggest anything

Comment: Are you compiling with that directory as your working directory? Just to be sure...

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check it? How can I set working directory?

Comment: If your IDE is not helping, first get it working directly, open up a command window `cd` to the folder that has got your document and the .sty file and type `pdflatex zzzz` (whatever your document is called) then if latex finds the file and makes a pdf with no error you know tex is working and it's just a matter of teaching your editor to do what you just did.

Comment: I do it - the problem is the same. I am really confused. I am sure that in one, the same folder I have my document and lifecon file. It is really strange...

Comment: post what dir or ls -l or whatever operating system file list is on your system, listcon.sty needs to be there, not compressed, and readable permissions

Comment: I think the problem is that this file is write as *.txt but latex expect *.sty file. Thus, maybe should I convert this file from *.txt to *.sty ? Is there way to do it?